# logstash->kafka->logstash->elasticsearch dropping some logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka

i have a `logstash->kafka->logstash->elasticsearch` setup. `logstash` is tailing on a log file. this log file is being appended to with `bunyan` in `nodejs` and everything is set to `json` format/codec. it seems to me any log entry that contains an empty array somewhere doesn't get delivered to the destination. does any one know what the problem is? is `kafka` not designed to take in json objects with empty lists? `logstash`'s `kafka` output plugin is pretty new, are there known issues related to that? I couldn't find out anything from my google search...

Answer (score 2):

I would do 2 things to check the root source of the problem:

- Add a file appender to the first logstash, and then check if the empty array is being written to the file or not. Architecture would look like this: **logstash -> file, kafka -> logstash -> elasticsearch**
- Read from the kafka topic yourself and check if the empty array is being written or not. You can do this using [Apache Kafka Python Plugin](https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python)

That way, you could check if the problem is in the logstash plugin side (more likely) or the kafka side (less likely because kafka basically just read/write bytes, and does not familiar with the content itself).

Comment: I still haven't figured out the problem but the problem is with neither `logstash` nor `kafka`, logs appeared at the consumer if i ask the `logstash` consumer to write to file. So might be something off with my `elasticsearch` configuration.

Comment: It maybe has something to do with your client? or encoding configuration?

Comment: Mapping conflict? Go to admin in Kibana, check the relevant index and see if there’s a mapping conflict. If there is, ES will drop messages